# Using multiple "by"s in a compound sentence

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, by-with

Which one is correct in the following sentences?

1. Due to the peculiar device operation, the avalanche can be triggered not only **by** photogenerated carriers but also **by** carriers thermally generated or **by** trapping levels in the semiconductor.
2. Due to the peculiar device operation, the avalanche can be triggered not only **by** photogenerated carriers but also carriers thermally generated or trapping levels in the semiconductor.

Do I need to use the **by** that many times in a compound sentence?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confusion and ambiguity I would keep the "by".

How can the avalanche be triggered? There are three possibilities:

by photogenerated carriers;

by carriers thermally generated;

by trapping levels in the semiconductor.

If "by" is omitted, we might understand a fourth and erroneous possibility:

by carriers thermally generated or trapping levels in the semiconductor. (The non-technical reader may wrongly imagine carriers that are either thermally generated in the semiconductor or are somehow "trapping levels" in it.)

Comment: What if there are only two possibilities? Then can I omit the by?

Comment: I suspect that *by* is needed when the items in the list are not *perceived* as mutually exclusive. *Raise new plants by grafting or planting seed* has the troublesome ambiguity that suggests (although wrongly) that seed may be grafted or planted. Better is *... by grafting or by planting seed.* But *We won by accident or design* contains two mutually exclusive notions (*accident* and *design*) so does not need the second *by*.